# Gradle cannot download from remote maven repository

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

On few github libraries like in here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless I found references to repository stored on amazon.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:endless:1.2.3'
}
```

Problem is, that I can't make it works in gradle to download dependency from this kind of repository.

Here is example of my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'android-maven'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo.commonsware.com/"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:endless:1.2.3'
    compile project(':FontLibrary')
}
```

I am using Intellij Idea 13 and the result is:

```
Gradle 'OSKExplorer' project refresh failed:
         Could not find com.commonsware.cwac:endless:1.2.3.
         Required by:
         OSKExplorer:SwipeListViewComponent:unspecified > OSKExplorer:CommonLibrary:unspecified
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Try to remove `mavenLocal()` (which you probably don't want anyway).

Comment: Also, try the `https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com` URL, as that is the one I test with my demo apps.

Comment: I tested both, also [link](https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com). Problem seems to be, if there is maven central repo, then it all trying to download from repo1.maven...etc url. When I removed mavenCentral() it tried to download from commonsware repo, but died on other dependencies. I tried every combination of repo order, but same result.

Comment: Obviously in different project it suddenly working.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if using the https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com URL did it for you, but I'd put that maven{url} bit in like so:

```
allprojects{
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
        maven{ url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"}
    }
}
```

gl!

Comment: I had similar problem, but error was about certificate `Certificate for <repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names`. And URL can be also defined as 
`maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"}`
Then it passes certificate check fine.

Answer (score 2):

replace the https to http like this, http://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com

it's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The url is not correct. Use this one works for me

```
maven {url "http://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    maven {

        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

with

```
repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    maven {

        url "http://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
    maven {
        url "http://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```