# gradle android commonsware not found maven

Tags: android, maven, gradle, commonsware-cwac

App build is failing with the below error message

> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not find any version that matches com.commonsware.cwac:colormixer:0.6.+.

```
repositories {
    maven {
       url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:colormixer:0.6.+'
}
```

After changing gradle version 2.2.1 instaed of 1.11 it gives like this error:

> 2014-12-23 16:03:16,849 [ 215344]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - You are using Gradle version 1.9, which is not supported by the version of the Android Gradle plug-in the project is using. Please use version 1.10.
>   Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.) 
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: You are using Gradle version 1.9, which is not supported by the version of the Android Gradle plug-in the project is using. Please use version 1.10.
>   Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)

Can anybody help why 'ColorMixer' lib is not being found?

Comment: Try with http instead of https

Comment: I've already tested, no response?

Comment: I think it depends the version of gradle, i'm using gradle 1.10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353148/gradle-cannot-download-from-remote-maven-repository check this link

Comment: I`ve changed 'mavenCentral()' into 'jcenter()' also, no response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies. I was dealing with some problems with my Maven repo yesterday. While I fixed most projects, `colormixer` was one I missed.

The problem is fixed now, though it may require you to run **`gradle --refresh-dependencies`** to get Gradle to pick up the formerly-missing artifact.

Comment: I have updated my gradle to 3.0 and getting exception like Could not resolve com.commonsware.cwac:colormixer:0.6.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/commonsware/cwac/colormixer/0.6.1/colormixer-0.6.1.pom'.

Comment: @nAkhmedov: You appear to have an old URL in your `repositories` closure. Change it to `https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Helped

Comment: @nAkhmedov: I don't know. Usually, the old URL fails, because Amazon changed (removed?) their SSL wildcard certificate for `s3.amazonaws.com`, so `https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com` is rejected for an invalid certificate. I have had plenty of people complain about the old URL failing before Gradle 3.0 shipped, so I don't know how your environment was working. Regardless, you should be OK now.